MVC model programming based on the QAbstractListModel,setEditorData function did not refresh correctly, results in the displayed data incorrect."
this is my wlanmode.cpp
#include "wlanmodel.h"
#include <networkinterface.h>
#include <QImage>
#include "union-dbus-network-interface.h"


const int NM_DEVICE_TYPE_WIFI = 2;
const int CONNECT_TYPE_WIRELESS = 14;

WlanModel::WlanModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    //m_data = UnionNetworkDBusInterface::Instance()->networkInterface()->wifiList();
    //m_data<<"redflag_5G1"<<"redflag_5G2"<<"redflag_5G3"<<"redflag_5G4"<<"redflag_5G5"<<"redflag_5G6";
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G1",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G2",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G3",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G4",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G5",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G6",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    m_data.insert("redflag_5G7",":/strongwlansignal.svg");
    qDebug()<<"--------variantmap"<<m_data;

}

int WlanModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : m_data.size();
}

QVariant WlanModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return m_data.keys().at(index.row());
    } else if (role == Qt::DecorationRole) {
        return QImage(m_data.values().at(index.row()).toString());
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QString WlanModel::getKey(int index) const
{
    QStringList keys = m_data.keys();
    qDebug()<<"keys ===="<<keys;
    return index >= 0 && index < keys.size() ? keys.at(index) : QString();
}

QVariant WlanModel::getValueByKey(const QString &key) const
{
    return m_data.value(key, QVariant());
}

this is my wlandelegate.cpp
#include "wlandelegate.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <rf-widget/rlabel.h>
#include <rf-widget/rbackgroundframe.h>
#include <rf-widget/rpushbutton.h>

#define TableControllerSpacing 20

WlanDelegate::WlanDelegate(QListView *listView,QObject *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent),
      m_listView(listView)
{
}

void WlanDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    painter->save();
    // 获取项的矩形区域
    QRect rect = option.rect;

    // 如果需要选中效果，设置不同的背景颜色
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        painter->fillRect(rect, option.palette.color(QPalette::Window).lighter());
        //p.setBrush(opt.palette.color(QPalette::Window).lighter());
    } else {
        painter->fillRect(rect, option.palette.base());
    }

    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    // 禁用焦点框的绘制
    opt.state &= ~QStyle::State_HasFocus;

    // 调用父类的绘制行为
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);

    // 恢复绘制状态
    painter->restore();
}

QSize WlanDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QSize(300, 82);  // 设置每一项的大小
}

QWidget *WlanDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QWidget *editor = new QWidget(parent);
    editor->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout(editor));  // 设置布局，具体的控件将在setEditorData中添加
    return editor;
}

void WlanDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    // 清除既有布局中的所有控件
    QLayout *pLayout = editor->layout();
    QLayoutItem *item;
    while ((item = pLayout->takeAt(0)) != nullptr)
    {
        delete item->widget();
        delete item;
    }

    // 创建并添加新的控件
//    QLabel *iconLabel = new QLabel(editor);
//    QLabel *textLabel = new QLabel(editor);
//    QImage wlanImage;
//    wlanImage.load(index.data(Qt::DecorationRole).toString());
//    iconLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(wlanImage));
    QString key = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
//    textLabel->setText(key);
    QPushButton *pConnectAndDisconnectButton = new QPushButton(editor);
    pConnectAndDisconnectButton->setText(key);
    QHBoxLayout *pHlayout = new QHBoxLayout(editor);
    pHlayout->addSpacerItem(tabelControllerspacing);
    pHlayout->addWidget(iconLabel);
    pHlayout->addWidget(textLabel);
    editor->setLayout(pHlayout);
}

void WlanDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
}

void WlanDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

}

in  setEditorData function i init my layout then
this is my using of wlanmode mvc in my mainwindow
 WlanDelegate *delegate = new WlanDelegate(m_pListView, this);
 m_pListView->setItemDelegate(delegate);
 m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pTitlebackgroundFrame);
 m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pListView);
 setLayout(m_pMainLayout);

then i get a image
enter image description here
then no matter how i change setEditorData function,i always get the same picture,why my setEditorData function doesn't work later.
i change my code here
void WlanDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    editor->setFixedSize(300,82);
    QLayout *pLayout = editor->layout();
    QLayoutItem *item;
    while ((item = pLayout->takeAt(0)) != nullptr)
    {
        delete item->widget();
        delete item;
    }

    // 创建并添加新的控件
    QLabel *iconLabel = new QLabel(editor);
    QLabel *textLabel = new QLabel(editor);
    QImage wlanImage;
    wlanImage.load(index.data(Qt::DecorationRole).toString());
    iconLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(wlanImage));
    QString key = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    textLabel->setText(key);
    QPushButton *pConnectAndDisconnectButton = new QPushButton(editor);
    pConnectAndDisconnectButton->setText(key);
    QHBoxLayout *pHlayout = new QHBoxLayout(editor);
    pHlayout->addSpacing(30);
    pHlayout->addWidget(iconLabel);
    pHlayout->addWidget(textLabel);
    pHlayout->addWidget(pConnectAndDisconnectButton);
    editor->setLayout(pHlayout);
}

and addSpacindg,setContetMargin doesn't work,for exapmple {pHlayout->addSpacing(30);}doesn't work,and i add new controller in my layout doesn't work. I expect that they can work and i hope i can add new controllers.I hope after i addSpacing in
my layout the icon and wifissidname can move right,but it seems that it doesn't work in my new code

Welcome to SO. Please read the article named How to ask and follow instructions to write a question we can asnwer. In particular, do describe your expected result vs current result (i.e. what you currently have, not what you have after commenting parts of your code). I have no idea what you are complaining about right now.

ok i add my expected result and current reult

So you do addSpacing on the QHBoxLayout then add 3 widgets to the layout; the 3 widgets are stuck to the very left of the editor's layout, at least more so than where you'd expect the spacing would force them to, is that it? And setContentMargins with a large left margin does not appear to work either?

You already have a layout, don't create a new one (which you cannot set, since one already exists), use the existing one. Remove the QHBoxLayout *pHlayout = new QHBoxLayout(editor); line near the bottom.

@Atmo，Yes,add spacing and setContentMargins all don't work.

@musicamante my origin codes is here pHlayout->addWidget(iconLabel);
pHlayout->addWidget(textLabel);
editor->setLayout(pHlayout);

@任欣禹 As already said, you already have a layout set in createEditor(), so you must use even in setEditorData(). setLayout() does not work if another layout is already set, and since you were going to use a similar layout (QHBoxLayout), creating a new one makes absolutely no sense anyway.
